# my extension of string runs before appDelegate why this happens?

Tags: swift, appdelegate

In `appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I store value in `UserDefaults` as follows:

```
  UserDefaults.standard.setValue("fr", forKey: "selectedLocale")
```

and I have one `extension` of `String` where I access the value I previously stored in `UserDefaults` but there I got `nil`. When I tried to debug the code, I got to know that the extension was running before the `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`

can anyone explain why this happened?

Thanx in advance

My code is as follows:

**For appDelegate:**

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   /*----------------- Setting Locale on App Launch ------------------*/
    // UserDefaults.standard.setValue((UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as! [Any])[0], forKey: USER_DEFAULT.selectedLocale)
    let country = NSLocale.current
    if let locale = country.collatorIdentifier {
        if locale.contains("en") {
            Singleton.sharedInstance.currentLocale = "en"
        } else {
            Singleton.sharedInstance.currentLocale = "fr"
        }
    } else {
        Singleton.sharedInstance.currentLocale = "fr"
    }
    Singleton.sharedInstance.isRTL = false
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Singleton.sharedInstance.currentLocale, forKey: USER_DEFAULT.selectedLocale)
  }
```

**And For extension:**

```
  extension String {
        var localized: String {
              let locale = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: USER_DEFAULT.selectedLocale) as? String
              if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: locale, ofType: "lproj") {
                    let bundle = Bundle(path: path)
                    return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
              }
        return self
        }
  }
```

Comment: Can you lookup by stacktrace who call your extension method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `extension String` will call when any of string initialize. in your code `currentLocale`.For my Opinion you need to create function in `extension` and call it when you store value.

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Singleton.sharedInstance.currentLocale, forKey: USER_DEFAULT.selectedLocale) 
Singleton.sharedInstance.currentLocale.loadNib() //function in extension
```

example

```
extension String {
     func loadNib() {
         let locale = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: USER_DEFAULT.selectedLocale) as? String
         if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: locale, ofType: "lproj") {
            let bundle = Bundle(path: path)
            return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't got what you trying to say by this? `Singleton.sharedInstance.currentLocale.loadNib() //function in extension
`

Comment: @sanjaykmwt what is use of  `localized ` in your `extension` ?

Comment: it gives me the localized string for the specific word I call localized with. Means if my phone language is french it will return me the french equivalent string for it

Comment: bro you forgot to mention the return type for the function

Comment: and can you explain what difference it will make if I use function instead of computed property

Comment: @sanjaykmwt feel free to update my answer.if i miss anything :)